# error in deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, tomcat, jboss

am trying since to deploy a GWT project in jboss and i have this error

---

```
> 18:59:51,074 ERROR
> [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error
> installing to PreReal:
> name=vfs:///home/chun/Documents/dev/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/deploy/t1.war
> state=PostClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PreReal:
> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: t1.server.GreetingServiceImpl from
> BaseClassLoader@47bebb{vfs:///home/chun/Documents/dev/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/deploy/t1.war}
>   at
> org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:257)
> [:6.0.0.Final]    at
> org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.scan(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:108)
> [:6.0.0.Final]    at
> org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.internalDeploy(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:64)
> [:6.0.0.Final]    at
> org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
> [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
> [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
> [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
> [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
> [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
> [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
> [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
> [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106)
> [:6.0.0.Final]    at
> org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_30]
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> t1.server.GreetingServiceImpl from
> BaseClassLoader@47bebb{vfs:///home/chun/Documents/dev/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/deploy/t1.war}
>   at
> org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:480)
> [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]  at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_30]     at
> org.jboss.resteasy.integration.deployers.ResteasyScannerDeployer.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(ResteasyScannerDeployer.java:253)
> [:6.0.0.Final]    ... 41 more 18:59:51,117 WARN 
> [org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner] Scan failed:
> org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary
> of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):
> *** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error vfs:///home/chun/Documents/dev/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/deploy/t1.war
> -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: t1.server.GreetingServiceImpl from
> BaseClassLoader@47bebb{vfs:///home/chun/Documents/dev/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/deploy/t1.war}
> DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:   Deployment
> "vfs:///home/chun/Documents/dev/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/deploy/t1.war"
> is in error due to the following reason(s):
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: t1.server.GreetingServiceImpl from
> BaseClassLoader@47bebb{vfs:///home/chun/Documents/dev/jboss-6.0.0/server/default/deploy/t1.war}
>   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968)
> [:2.2.0.GA]   at
> org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82)
> [:6.0.0.Final]    at
> org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.checkComplete(ProfileControllerContext.java:138)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:246)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90)
> [:0.2.2]  at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
> [:1.6.0_30]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_30]
```

---

this is my web.xml file

```
<web-app> 
  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>t1.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/t1/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>T1.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

this is my servlet code:

```
package t1.server;

import t1.client.GreetingService;
import t1.shared.FieldVerifier;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

/**
 * The server side implementation of the RPC service.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        GreetingService {

    public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Verify that the input is valid. 
        if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(input)) {
            // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException back to
            // the client.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Name must be at least 4 characters long");
        }

        String serverInfo = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
        String userAgent = getThreadLocalRequest().getHeader("User-Agent");

        // Escape data from the client to avoid cross-site script vulnerabilities.
        input = escapeHtml(input);
        userAgent = escapeHtml(userAgent);

        return "Hello, " + input + "!<br><br>I am running " + serverInfo
                + ".<br><br>It looks like you are using:<br>" + userAgent;
    }

    /**
     * Escape an html string. Escaping data received from the client helps to
     * prevent cross-site script vulnerabilities.
     * 
     * @param html the html string to escape
     * @return the escaped string
     */
    private String escapeHtml(String html) {
        if (html == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return html.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
                .replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
    }
}
```

am trying since to fixe this without succes. can somebody help me?
and please forgive my english level !!!

this is the folder's structure:

```
-----t1
 |     `-----gwt
 |      |     `-----clean
 |      |      |     `-----images
`-----WEB-INF
 |     `-----classes
 |      |     `-----t1
 |      |      |     `-----client
 |      |      |     `-----server
 |      |      |     `-----shared
 |     `-----deploy
 |      |     `-----t1
 |      |      |     `-----rpcPolicyManifest
 |      |      |      |     `-----manifests
 |     `-----lib
```

Comment: Can you provide the folder structure for your war?

Comment: Where in `t1.war` is `GreetingServiceImpl.class`?

Comment: the GreetingServicelmp.class is as this link      :$HOME/workspace/t1/war/WEB-INF/classes/t1/server

Comment: How are you calling the server from your client?

Comment: i am using the sample that GWt provide when you are creating a new project. i haven' t changed anything.  when i modify the return of the method in the servlet in eg:## return "aaaaa" ### it work so the problem is may be about these return but i don' t understand why. Anyway a great tks for every body. it is good to see that you are not alone in the world.